# Azure load balancer session persistence

Tags: iis, azure, virtual-machines

I have an azure load balancer, in the backend pool , I have 2 windows VM, in each VM I have the same web application replicated, in load distribution I am using session IP, so request from my browser or machine was always going to vm2, which I understand it is due to session persistence, but when I stopped the IIS in vm2 and browsed the front end iP the load balancer, instead of routing the request to vm1 it still redirects my request to vm2

Comment: How is your load balancer probe setup? How often is it polling? Is is checking port 443 (or whatever port your website is on) or is it a different probe type? How long did you wait between shutting down IIS and testing browsing again?